# Error with parsing json

Tags: java, json, jackson

I write code to read json file, but have error:

[image]

```
private static void parseJSON(JsonParser jsonParser, Response resp, Result res) throws JsonParseException, IOException
    {
        try{        
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();

        List<Result> ress = null;
        JsonParser jp = new JsonFactory().createParser(new File("C:\\Users\\Ismr\\work2\\response.json"));
        TypeReference<List<Result>> tRes = new TypeReference<List<Result>>() {};
        ress=mapper.readValue(jp, tRes);

        for (Result result : ress) {
            System.out.println(result.toString());
        }

    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

All library install. what I do wrong?

Comment: error description ?

Comment: try using readValues() instead of readValue().

Comment: @DerickDaniel error- Configurate bild path, but jackson-mapper-asl-1.9.13.jar I install, readValues() doesn't work

Comment: clean and build your project

Comment: @DerickDaniel it's not work(

Comment: "Configure build path" is a suggestion of Eclipse. It is _not_ the error message. Please tell us the complete error message! I guess, you get a "symbol undefined", which simply means that the needed library is _not_ part of your build path, or you are using the wrong elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Json Simple library You Can Write.
You failed to give how be your json.
Even this Code May Help you.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

    public class JsonHelper {
        public static void main() {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("Key","value");
            jsonObject.put("Key1","value1");

            JSONArray sensorJsonArray = new JSONArray();
                JSONObject simple = new JSONObject();
                simple.put("JsonArrayKey","JsonArrayValue");
                simple.put("JsonArrayKey1","JsonArrayValue1");
                simple.put("JsonArrayKey2","JsonArrayValue2");
                sensorJsonArray.add(simple);

            try(FileWriter file = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Ismr\\work2\\response.json")) {
                jsonObject.put("Array", sensorJsonArray);
                file.write(jsonObject.toJSONString());
                file.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```